# SQLServer 2008, Query for filename format s

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to retrieve all the files which needs to be navigate through the predefined folder and filename need to be of certain format,
Like example:
`V<XXXXX>.doc` or `<XXXXXX>.doc`

Where  file name is varchar, but  is the numbers from 0 to 9
 (the exact pattern of file name would be V012134.doc or 3213424.doc)

```
select filename from table1 where filename LIKE '%<> %'
```

Can you please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: File name format v<XXXXX>.doc or <XXXX>.doc  and X is number from 0 to 9

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, what exact pattern do you want to match?

Comment: Apologies, the exact pattern of file name  would be V012134.doc or 3213424.doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(fn VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('V<123123213>.doc'),
('A123123213.doc'),
('V<V1>.doc'),
('VV<1>.doc'),
('V<1>.doc'),
('V<1>V.doc'),
('V<1V>.doc'),
('VV.doc'),
('<>.doc'),
('<123>.doc'),
('<12A3>.doc')


SELECT fn
FROM @t 
WHERE (fn LIKE 'V<%[0-9]%>.doc' OR fn LIKE '<%[0-9]%>.doc') AND 
SUBSTRING(fn, 
          CHARINDEX('<', fn) + 1, 
          CHARINDEX('>', fn) - CHARINDEX('<', fn) - 1) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Explanation: select rows where file name starts with `V`(or not), followed by `<`, followed by at least 1 digit, followed by  `>.doc` and substring between `<` and `>` does not contain symbols other than digits.

Output:

```
fn
V<123123213>.doc
V<1>.doc
<123>.doc
```

Without `<>`:

```
SELECT fn
FROM @t 
WHERE (fn LIKE 'V%[0-9]%.doc' AND SUBSTRING(fn, 2, CHARINDEX('.doc', fn) - 2) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') or
      (fn LIKE '%[0-9]%.doc' AND REPLACE(fn, '.doc', '') NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Another question, if we have another file extension, .pdf along with .doc what would be the best way to filter out... I mean i need to include both .doc and .pdf files

Comment: `((fn LIKE 'V%[0-9]%.doc' OR fn LIKE 'V%[0-9]%.pdf') AND `

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `like` and `not like`:

```
where (fn like 'V%.doc' and fn not like 'V%[^0-9]%.doc') or
      (fn like '%.doc' and fn not like '%[^0-9]%.doc')
```

or you can combine these as:

```
where fn like '[V0-9]%.doc' and fn not like '[V0-9]%[^0-9]%.doc'
```

The `like` validates the characters that need to be in the filename.  The `not like` checks that there are no non-digits where they should not be.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will match the exact number of digits. e.g. -
`'<XX>.doc'` will match `35.doc` but not `5.doc` or `357.doc`

```
Declare @format varchar(100) = 'V<XXXXX>.doc'

select  filename 
from    table1 
where   filename LIKE replace(replace(replace(@format,'<',''),'>',''),'X','[0-9]')
```